# c# simple update query not working

Tags: c#

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SAI\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testing;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
string test = "UPDATE attend Year='2014' WHERE Id = '2'";
command = new SqlCommand(test, conn);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Year and id are both `varchar`. Error is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Year'.

Comment: You are missing a SET before Year

Comment: That error should be more than enough for you to run off of

Comment: The first thing I do, when I have an error in my SQL, is to open a query tool (like SQL Server Management Studio) and run the query directly against the database, so I can see the more detailed error message that it will provide.

Answer (score 3):

Should be :

```
UPDATE attend SET Year='2014' WHERE Id = '2'
```